# Definition of *pure* transcendental extension

Tags: definition, extension-field

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Transcendental_extension), an extension is *pure* transcendental extension if and only if there exists a transcendence basis $S$ (algebraically independent subset) of $L/K$ such that $L = K(S)$. Of course $S$ is a set of transcendental elements, and it is obvious that if a set $S'$ is a set of transcendental elements, then it is not necessarily an algebraically independent subset of $L$ (for example $\{\pi,\pi+1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$).

If we are able to find such $S'\subset L$ where $L=K(S')$, but $S'$ is not algebraically independent, is $L/K$ considered to be a *pure* transcendental extension?

Comment: It might be, it might not be.

Comment: @TrevorGunn But what is the exact definition to pure transcendental extension?

Comment: Transcendental basis of $L/K$ means that any element $s\in S$ is transcendental over $K(S-s)$ and that $L$ is algebraic over $K(S)$.

Comment: The standard example of a non-purely transcendental extension is the elliptic curve $\Bbb{C}(x,\sqrt{x^3+1})$. Not convinced there are easier examples of finitely generated non-purely transcendental extensions of an algebraically closed field. $\overline{\Bbb{Q}(\pi)}/\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is clearly not purely transcendental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension $L/K$ is purely transcendental if there exists *some* algebraically independent set $S$ such that $L = K(S)$.

Every extension $L/K$ can be written as $K(S)$ for some set $S$ (e.g. $S = L$) but maybe or maybe not with $S$ being algebraically independent.

For instance, with $\mathbf{Q}(x) / \mathbf{Q}$ I can take $S = \{x, x^2\}$ or $S_2 = \{x\}$. One of these is algebraically independent and the other is not.

Or $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2}, x)/\mathbf{Q}$ I can take $S_1 = \{\sqrt{2}, x\}$ or $S_2 = \{\sqrt{2}, x + \frac37\sqrt{2}, x^2, \frac{1 - x + x^2}{1 - \sqrt{2}}\}$ but never with $S$ being algebraically independent.